# Restrict generic key type based on lookup type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics

I'm working on a function that takes two type parameters, `T` and `K`. `T` extends a `Record` type and `K` is a key of the first type. Is there a way I can restrict the key type based on its lookup type (`T[K]`) in `T`?

I have the following types:

```
type FormValue = string | number | boolean | null;

type FormValues = Record<string, FormValue>;
```

and the following function:

```
function numericFormHelperFunc<T extends FormValues, K extends keyof T>(key: K, formValues: T) {}
```

Is there a way I can restrict which keys can be used for this function so that only keys in `formValues` that have lookup types of, say, `number` are allowed? Basically a way to assert that `T[K] extends number`.

For example if I have this example form type:

```
type MyFormValues = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    numPets: number;
}
```

Can I add a type restriction to `numericFormHelperFunc` so that only the keys `"age"` and `"numPets"` could be used?

I'm looking for a static way to do this so that I'll get editor warnings about trying to use `numericFormHelperFunc("name", myFormValues)`. Also would like for typescript to know that the value from looking up `key` in `formValues` is of a specific type, rather than just `T[K]` (e.g. so that number-specific methods and operators can be used without type assertions).

Comment: Is this ok for you https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gJwLYDUCGAbArtAvFAZ2AQEsA7AcygB8oyskAjCBGqRuODCNMt+jBgDcAKBGhIsRKkw4CUfACUIAY0QATADxFSlADRTk6bBAB8o8eGgBZEPCOyI8-AG8RUD3TRIIALkLE5BSinlBoFH50DMwIIZ70SAAKEMAE-gkxogC+YgBmWGQqwCRwfAksJCr2SAASEBiQCDAFKpoAKlAQAB7AEGTq8tXGcqYAFADWECD+kyBwuVC2Q44EBrnSw07+bQCUUC45QA ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```js
type FormValue = string | number | boolean | null;

type FormValues = Record<string, FormValue>;

type MyFormValues = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  numPets: number;
}

/**
 * Takes two arguments,
 * T - indexed type
 * Allowed - allowed types
 * 
 * Iterates through all properties and check
 * if property extends allowed value
 */
type Filter<T, Allowed> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Allowed ? P : never
}[keyof T]

function numericFormHelperFunc<T extends FormValues>(key: Filter<MyFormValues, number>, formValues: T) { }

numericFormHelperFunc('age', {'sdf':'sdf'}) // ok
numericFormHelperFunc('numPets', {'sdf':'sdf'}) // ok
numericFormHelperFunc('hello', {'sdf':'sdf'}) // error
numericFormHelperFunc('2', {'sdf':'sdf'}) // error
numericFormHelperFunc('name', {'sdf':'sdf'}) // error
```

Comment: For insight, the reason this works is because `AnyType | never === AnyType`.

Comment: That plus the `[keyof T]` line at the end, yeah.

Comment: Definitely addresses the main point of my question, thank you. This might require opening a separate question, but is there a way to have the editor know about the underlying type when using a lookup type? In this case would be nice to be able to treat the value for the given key as a `number` without having to do any type assertions. Is this possible?

Comment: Seems this is possible if using the actual type `FormValues` but not with `T extends FormValues` (at least without extra handling).

Comment: Not sure it is possible